# Adding custom column in order grid, removes toolbar from page

Tags: magento2.3.1, order-grid

In administration Orders Grid, I added a custom column containing telephone. I used a custom extension for this and it causes order toolbar to disappear somehow
[image]

Here's the module code:

**etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="custom_orders_grid" type="Company\Module\Plugin\OrdersGrid" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/OrdersGrid.php**
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Plugin;

```
class OrdersGrid
{
    public function afterGetReport($subject, $collection, $requestName)
    {
        if ($requestName !== 'sales_order_grid_data_source')
        {
            return $collection;
        }

        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_grid'))
        {
            $orderAddressTable  = $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales_order_address');

            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                ['oat' => $orderAddressTable],
                'oat.parent_id = main_table.entity_id AND oat.address_type = \'shipping\'',
                ['telephone']
            );
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">

        <column name="telephone">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add
`<listingToolbar name="listing_top"/>` in sales_order_grid.xml. So it finally looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top"/> 

    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="telephone">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
    
</listing>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do the same first we need to create a `sales_order_grid.xml` file at this path using below code.
**app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
         <column name="newfield" class="Vendor\Extension\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Newcolumn">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
         </column>
       </columns>
</listing>
```

Now you have to create one more file `Newcolumn.php` at following location.
**app\code\Vendor\Extension\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Newcolumn.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
 
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
 
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
 
class Newcolumn extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;
 
    public function __construct(
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
 
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $order->getData("newfield");
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

That’s it, now clear the cache and you will able to see newly added comment in backend sales order grid view. You are free add multiple custom column using above code.

Comment: Can you edit your code, using Telephone as data for the new column?

Answer (score 1):

It's not ok to use `$this->_orderRepository->get` inside loop. That action will slow down your grid loading speed.

You can do this way:

1. Add phone number column to sales_order_grid table. For this create db_schema.xml file in etc directory of your module and add (in case you need shipping phone number):

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="sales_order_grid" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Flat Order Grid">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="phone" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Ship Phone"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

2. Then in di.xml file (etc folder) add following code

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="ProperXT\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="phone" xsi:type="string">sales_shipping_address.telephone</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

3. Add phone to `Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<column name="phone" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Order\Columns\Phone">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <sortable>true</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

4. Create `Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Order\Columns\Phone` class

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Order\Columns;


class Phone extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                if (isset($item[$fieldName])) {
                    $item[$fieldName] = $this->getHtml($item[$fieldName]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }

    private function getHtml($phone)
    {
        return "<a href='tel:$phone'>$phone</a>";
    }
}
```